# Qt 5 repaint() in timer does not trigger paintEvent immediately

Tags: c++, qt, timer

I am using the MinGW build on Windows 7 of Qt 5.7.0.
I have created and started a timer which calls repaint() for my widget but paintEvent() is not triggered immediately afterwards although the documenation states this. Is this a bug (something like https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-4453) or my mistake? Is there an alternative how I can force the widget to be repainted since I can only paint inside the paintEvent() method and I need to draw some pictures etc. The timer debugging output from its to tick() connected slot comes much more often than the debugging output from paintEvent(). When I change the focus to another window and back, the painted stuff is always up to date.

My timer construction:

```
connect(this->m_paintTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updatePaint()));
```

...

```
void RoomWidget::updatePaint()
{
        qDebug() << "Repaint";
        this->repaint();
        qDebug() << "Debug: Repaint end";
}
```

...

```
void RoomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
    qDebug() << "Paint event";

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);
    ...
    qDebug() << "Paint event end";
}
```

...

```
m_paintTimer->start(ROOM_REPAINT_INTERVAL_MS);
```

...

```
const int ROOM_REPAINT_INTERVAL_MS = 200;
```

Ironically, this does perfectly work on Fedora.

edit:
My main window is using full screen mode by default. When not using full screen mode, it seems to work and prints:

```
Debug: Repaint
Debug: Paint event
Debug: Paint event end
Debug: Repaint end
Debug: Repaint
Debug: Paint event
Debug: Paint event end
Debug: Repaint end
Debug: Repaint
Debug: Paint event
Debug: Paint event end
Debug: Repaint end
Debug: Repaint
Debug: Paint event
Debug: Paint event end
Debug: Repaint end
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your actual *problem* is. You could perhaps write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a single .cpp file which demonstrates the problem ([here's an example](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/blob/master/questions/widgets-noob-22789705/main.cpp) by Kuba Ober on how to do it, notice the `#include "main.moc"` at the end).

Comment: Also, what issues arise, if you just use `update()` instead of `repaint()`?

Comment: The actual problem is that the RoomWidget is not repainted whenever the timer ticks. It is only repainted sometimes, for example whenever I change the focus to another window and back to the window with the RoomWidget. update() does not guarantee that paintEvent() is called immediately according to the documentation, I've tested it with update() and it doesn't work as well. The documentation states "This function does not cause an immediate repaint;".

Comment: Yeah, but `update()` does cause repaint very quickly (like, as soon as your code returns to event loop, and event loop gets a chance to post paintEvent, so hopefully in a few milliseconds!). If it doesn't do repaint at all (until you move the window), then there is a bug somewhere. That MCVE would be great for determining this.

Comment: Okay, I would still prefer repaint(). I figured out that it seems to work when not using full screen for the main window. In this case it prints:

Debug: Repaint
Debug: Paint event
Debug: Paint event end
Debug: Repaint end
Debug: Repaint
Debug: Paint event
Debug: Paint event end
Debug: Repaint end
Debug: Repaint
Debug: Paint event
Debug: Paint event end
Debug: Repaint end
Debug: Repaint
Debug: Paint event
Debug: Paint event end
Debug: Repaint end

which is exactly what I want, so it has something to do with full screen.

Comment: Please make a testcase.

Comment: So I've created a testcase but the testcase works fine. There I've created a custom central widget which also has a timer and repaints every second. It works in full screen too. In my not working application the widget is a child of the central widget and added to the layout of the central widget. Does it have to be the central widget to work? At the moment I am not using a custom central widget but the standard one of the Main Window.